# C# Application to Zoom in/out the image in a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

I am somewhat new to programming in general, but I am eager to learn more and I was wondering if anyone could possibly help me out with an idea.

(***main goal***)

I want to make a simple program that consists of a C# Windows Forms Application that displays a preset image (of 6000x6000 pixel dimensions, SizeMode set to Zoom so the entire image is visible on the form at once) in a PictureBox that will take up the entire form practically, save for a space at the bottom of the form where I want to display a TrackBar that will allow you to zoom the image in and out; as well as a horizontal scroll bar at the base of the PictureBox, and a vertical scroll bar on the right side of the PictureBox to scroll around the map when it is zoomed, and I wanted to be able to control these scroll bars by either clicking and dragging in a corresponding direction on the PictureBox (preferred but not sure if its possible) or by using the scroll wheel on the mouse (probably easier but once again not sure).

(***reference***)

[ ***Here is my form completed exactly as I described, with a 6000x6000 placement holder demo texture in a PictureBox using SizeMode Zoom, as an example*** - THIS HAS BEEN HANDLED, NEXT PART OF THE PROBLEM IS UPDATED BELOW:]

(***addendum***)

The only issue I am having is the code, as I am pretty much greenhorn in that department. I have been working to learn Visual Studio's workflow, but I really could use some help.

Thank you so much in advance for anything you can help me with.

UPDATE:

After doing research on the subject and taking time to do some thinking, I have come up with the code listed below; but my problem is that when I pan my image too far, the image is allowed to be pulled too far over, thus exposing the panel behind it when the image is panned/pulled too far over to one corner. Also, when I zoom too far out, the image is allowed to become WAY smaller than the Picturebox.

[Panning issue, the grey parts of the panel are the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT8eS.jpg)

[Zoom issue, the grey parts of the panel are the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lMKb.png)

So, my last question: How would I go about revising the code below to 'lock' the image that I am panning and zooming from being allowed to pan or zoom outside of its frame and expose the panel behind it?

```
public partial class ImageZoomMainForm : Form
{
    Image img;
    Point mouseDown;
    int startx = 0;
    int starty = 0;
    int imgx = 0; 
    int imgy = 0;

    bool mousepressed = false;  
    float zoom = 1;

    public ImageZoomMainForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        string imagefilename = @"..\..\ViewPort_MAIN.tif";
        img = Image.FromFile(imagefilename);

        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();








        zoom = ((float)pictureBox.Width / (float)img.Width) * (img.HorizontalResolution / g.DpiX);

        pictureBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(imageBox_Paint);
    }

    private void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

        if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point mousePosNow = mouse.Location;

            int deltaX = mousePosNow.X - mouseDown.X; 
            int deltaY = mousePosNow.Y - mouseDown.Y;

            imgx = (int)(startx + (deltaX / zoom));  
            imgy = (int)(starty + (deltaY / zoom));

            pictureBox.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void imageBox_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;

        if (mouse.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (!mousepressed)
            {
                mousepressed = true;
                mouseDown = mouse.Location;
                startx = imgx;
                starty = imgy;
            }
        }
    }

    private void imageBox_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mousepressed = false;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        float oldzoom = zoom;

        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            zoom += 0.1F;
        }

        else if (e.Delta < 0)
        {
            zoom = Math.Max(zoom - 0.1F, 0.01F);
        }

        MouseEventArgs mouse = e as MouseEventArgs;
        Point mousePosNow = mouse.Location;

        int x = mousePosNow.X - pictureBox.Location.X;    
        int y = mousePosNow.Y - pictureBox.Location.Y;

        int oldimagex = (int)(x / oldzoom);  
        int oldimagey = (int)(y / oldzoom);

        int newimagex = (int)(x / zoom);     
        int newimagey = (int)(y / zoom);

        imgx = newimagex - oldimagex + imgx;  
        imgy = newimagey - oldimagey + imgy;

        pictureBox.Refresh();  


    }

    private void imageBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, imgx, imgy);
    }



    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

        if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Right:
                    imgx -= (int)(pictureBox.Width * 0.1F / zoom);
                    pictureBox.Refresh();
                    break;

                case Keys.Left:
                    imgx += (int)(pictureBox.Width * 0.1F / zoom);
                    pictureBox.Refresh();
                    break;

                case Keys.Down:
                    imgy -= (int)(pictureBox.Height * 0.1F / zoom);
                    pictureBox.Refresh();
                    break;

                case Keys.Up:
                    imgy += (int)(pictureBox.Height * 0.1F / zoom);
                    pictureBox.Refresh();
                    break;

                case Keys.PageDown:
                    imgy -= (int)(pictureBox.Height * 0.90F / zoom);
                    pictureBox.Refresh();
                    break;

                case Keys.PageUp:
                    imgy += (int)(pictureBox.Height * 0.90F / zoom);
                    pictureBox.Refresh();
                    break;
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    private void ImageZoomMainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Always dispose Graphics objects you make, by putting them in a `using(...) { }` block

Answer (score 0):

A picturebox inside a Panel, 
the panel should be set its AutoSroll to True,
the picturebox with SizeMode to Zoom

the trackbar change can increase and decrease the size of inside picturebox so that the outer panel will have auto scroll

dragging also possible using several mouse events of the picturebox.

Comment: So after staying up all night and doing research, I have come up with the following code; reflected in the updated main post